# Easiest and quickest way to authenticate GKE when creating GKE cluster via terraform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to create a GKE cluster via terraform on a test project, however it now asks me for a more complicated means of authentication and I was wondering if there is a nice quick  and easy way to authenticate? Like a copy-paste password or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are just running this from the command line, you'll need to install the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) and then run the following command prior to running Terraform:

```
gcloud init
gcloud auth application-default login
```

You can check out https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/gke for more info.

Note:  for a real automated deployment, you would not want to use `gcloud auth application-default login` but rather you'd set up a service account.

Comment: My bad, my problem was it was trying to enable basic authentication in the giant code pile so I had to track it down and remove it.